# MSGraph edit Excel in Swift

Tags: swift, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to edit Excel files using the msgraph api?
I have read the documentation with how you use workbook. But how can you send that input from Swift?

Comment: Are you broadly asking how to make  a REST API call from a Swift app?

Comment: From what I have understood the api doesnt support the workbook excel support yet. So either I have to make a request without the API or do you have better solution?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean by "without the API"? Do you mean without the preview SDK?

Comment: Im currently using the sdk. Since you have Excel in the betasection I thought you had figure out some way of edit excel files. But maybe im wrong

Comment: Microsoft Graph's Excel APIs are part of the v1.0 API. The documentation is [located here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/excel). I'm not sure what the status of support is with iOS SDK but the SDK itself is very much still in Preview/Beta.

Comment: Ye I read the dokumentation. But it doesn't exist in the sdk

Comment: Are you asking for a Swift SDK?  If so please request this on https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis